# Create a phantom node which takes up no space with forest 2.1.5

Tags: forest, linguistics

It is basically the same question as [Forest: Create phantom node which takes up no space?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380322/forest-create-phantom-node-which-takes-up-no-space) but the solution offered there does not work with forest 2.1.5. I want the phantom S not to take space. I tried setting the baseline to the phantom node, but this did not have any effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\begin{document}
\noindent

This is some very informative text, that is very informative.\\
\begin{forest}
[\phantom{S}
  [S, no edge, baseline
        [NP,name=np11
                [he]]
        [VP, name=vp1
          [V,name=v1    [knows]]]]
  [S, no edge, name=s2
        [V, name=vcoord, no edge [and, name=and, no edge]]
        [VP
           [V,name=v2 [loves]]
           [NP, name=np22 [this record, roof]]]]]
\draw (s2.south)--(np11.north)
      (vp1.south)--(np22.north);
\draw[thick] (vcoord.south)--(v1.north)
             (vcoord.south)--(v2.north)
             (vcoord.south)--(and.north);
\end{forest}



\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the output should look like, but load `forest` with `[linguistics]` as a package option rather than `\useforestibrary`.  Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Right now the figure takes the same space as if the \phantom{s} would be visible. Loading the package with an option produces different output. Surprising! But the problem does not disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the `phantom` key of `forest` rather than the `\phantom` macro, which just makes the S invisible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\noindent

This is some very informative text, that is very informative.\\
\begin{forest}
[S, phantom
  [S, no edge, baseline
        [NP,name=np11
                [he]]
        [VP, name=vp1
          [V,name=v1    [knows]]]]
  [S, no edge, name=s2
        [V, name=vcoord, no edge [and, name=and, no edge]]
        [VP
           [V,name=v2 [loves]]
           [NP, name=np22 [this record, roof]]]]]
\draw (s2.south)--(np11.north)
      (vp1.south)--(np22.north);
\draw[thick] (vcoord.south)--(v1.north)
             (vcoord.south)--(v2.north)
             (vcoord.south)--(and.north);
\end{forest}



\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]